# Google Maps Geolocation API key in Unity not working properly

Tags: c#, google-maps, unity-game-engine

I am building an application in Unity (5.4.4f1) that uses the Google Maps API.

It works perfectly so long as I don't add the API key. If I add the API key which I have created using console.developers.google.com I get this error: "You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading. 403 Forbidden". On google's website it is stated that "If you're using the API under the standard plan, you must use an API key set up in a project of your choice.". So although everything works great without having the API key added at the end of the address, I'm worried google might decide to block the app at some point because it is making unauthenticated requests.

The url I am using for making requests is:
*http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=____&zoom=____&size=____&scale=____&maptype=____*

but if I add "&key=____" at the end, it breaks

I get the same thing if I use it in an empty project with no addons to interfere with the request so it's not from that.

Any suggestions on how to fix it and is it ok to leave it without a key even when I release it to be used by the general public?

Comment: 1.If you are making a personal project that will be used by you only the go ahead without the key. 2.If you plan to release this app then you must use the key. Finally, if you really want answer, you should post the code you use to make the request.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my question. To get the "&key=____" to work I had to change some project settings which Google has added for additional security.

For people having the same problem - to fix it you need to do the following: in *Google's API Manager* you should go to *Library* then *Google Static Maps API* (since I'm using that) and then switch to the tab "URL signing secret". There you click "Allow unsigned usage" and you are done.

I tried using the "&signature=____" generated by the secret but that only works if you manually input it on each url change. I didn't see the encryption formula being shown there so I don't think you can script it to happen automatically